# No keyboard in wireless app for Saucy Touch 22?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, 13.10

I seem to have a problem with the recent touch release. I can't access the keyboard in the wireless application, however it does appear in Notes. I have restarted my Nexus 7 several times and it still has not appeared. I, to be honest, am wondering if I have done anything wrong. Unfortunately there is nothing message wise from system, which, frankly doesn't seem right, so debug info isn't included. Can anyone enlighten our community? I am using Lubuntu raring to install, if it helps.

Comment: I'm up to Saucy 24... is there any hope for the N7 for Ubuntu Touch?

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this, only on the nexus 4. It appears to be a bug with the saucy builds. I found a work around though:

1. Get a laptop that has the Ubuntu SDK installed. It must be on wifi, not ethernet.
2. Open the `Ubuntu SDK`
3. Under the tab where it says `Devices`, click on `Clone network config from host to device`

This will, as the button says, clone the network configuration to the device. Of course, If you are traveling, you willl need that laptop to be first connected to the Network you want to connect to, then repeat those steps. So this is not practical if you are on the go and you need wifi, but great for connect to your home network.

Hope this works.